# Roslyn: How to get .NET6.0 code compiled into one exe

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, roslyn

I'm trying to compile this C# code:

```
    using System;
    
    namespace test
    {
        internal static class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

into a single .exe file, by using Roslyn:

```
                var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

                var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("program.exe")
                    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.ConsoleApplication))
                    .AddReferences(Net60.References.All)
                    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

                EmitResult emitResult = compilation.Emit(Path.Combine(path, "program.exe"));

                if (emitResult.Success)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Compiled.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"The compiler has encountered {emitResult.Diagnostics.Length} errors", "Errors while compiling");
                    foreach (var diagnostic in emitResult.Diagnostics)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show($"{diagnostic.GetMessage()}\nLine: {diagnostic.Location.GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition.Line} - Column: {diagnostic.Location.GetLineSpan().StartLinePosition.Character}", "Error");
                    }
                }
```

There's no single error while compiling it. It compiles "correctly", but when i launch it this error popup in console: `Unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The specified file could not be found.`

While compiling via Visual Studio (to an .exe and a .dll) it works.

How can i get it working? I just need it to compile to one, single .exe file. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not with Roslyn; the .NET SDK has support for combining things into a single executable, but that's done as a part of publishing and isn't something Roslyn does directly. One thing to remember is that Roslyn is just one part of a much larger toolchain here.